# Problema ao comparar valor boleano vindo da função javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função `validaSenha` que estou usando que verifica a quantidade de caracteres e retorna `true` ou `false`.
Na ação do botão finalizar executo uma chamada na função dentro de um `if`, mas mesmo validando não emite o alerta.

Debugando, coloquei uma `alert(validaSenha($("#senha").val()))`, e está retornando corretamente.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse caso?

```
$("#btn-finalizar").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ( validaSenha($("#senha").val()) )
    alert('ok')

})

function validaSenha(senha) {
  var numeros = 0;
  var letras = 0;
  var caracteres = senha.split('');
  for (let car of caracteres) {
    if (car.match(/\d/)) numeros++; // se for numero
    else if (car.match(/\w/)) letras++; // se não for numero, pode ser letra
  }
  return (numeros+letras) >= 8 && (numeros + letras) == senha.length;
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou, tem certeza que não é um erro de digitação? Tens como colocar o html utilizado?

Comment: @Denis Rudnei de Souza Creio que o problema estava com caracteres que não são letras nem números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, o problema é que você não está contando o que é diferente de número e letra, como por exemplo carácter especial

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn-finalizar").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ( validaSenha($("#senha").val()) )
    alert('ok');
    else
    alert("não é válida");

})

function validaSenha(senha) {
  var numeros = 0;
  var letras = 0;
  var caracterSepcial = 0;
  var caracteres = senha.split('');
  for (let car of caracteres) {
    if (car.match(/\d/)) numeros++; // se for numero
    else if (car.match(/\w/)) letras++; // se não for numero, pode ser letra
 else caracterSepcial++; // se não for número nem letra
  }
  return (numeros+letras +caracterSepcial) >= 8 && (numeros + letras + caracterSepcial) == senha.length;
}

  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btn-finalizar" value="Validar" />

<input type="text" id="senha" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito bom. Eu, ainda, negaria o resultado duas vezes, para forçar a conversão pra `boolean`, independente de erros dentro da função (ex: `if (!!validaSenha($("#senha").val()))`)

Comment: @Arthur Siqueira aí CASO algum erro ocorra na função retornaria sempre false, é isso?

Comment: Mais ou menos. JavaScript usa tipagem dinâmica, o que significa que, se por algum acaso do destino, você resolver modificar a função pra retornar outros valores (como um código numérico pra o nível de segurança da senha, e usar o número zero como sendo "inválido"), a função vai continuar funcionando, porque `!0 === true`, e `!!0 === false`

Comment: Se valores como 0, `undefined`, '' (string vazia) ou `null` forem negados duas vezes, eles viram `false`, e se qualquer outro valor for negado duas vezes (incluindo objetos), ele se torna `true`

Comment: Dessa forma você garante que o código siga uma padronização, e funcione, independente de alterações posteriores

Comment: @Arthur Siqueira Foi o que eu imaginei.

Comment: Essa também é uma forma interessante de testar se uma string está vazia, se o usuário digitou valores nulos (0, campo vazio, etc) ou mesmo se a função está retornando o objeto que você precisa. Outra vantagem é que, por ser uma conversão, você pode usar em quase qualquer lugar, quando precisar evitar erros

Comment: @Arthur Siqueira Muito interessante, vou testar das próximas vezes, muito obrigado.

Comment: Mto obrigado Arthur!